# How to traverse DOM elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, tree-traversal

I'm still getting to grips with javascript, and am having trouble working out the correct syntax to select a DOM element. Would appreciate any points.

The html:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <label class="check_box_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    Checkbox Label
  </label>
  <select class="select">...</select>
</div>
```

When the checkbox value changes, if it is checked I want to do something with the select field (I'm using coffeescript)

```
jQuery ->
  $(".checkbox).change ->
    if $(this).is(":checked")
      $this.xxxxx(".select")
```

I've studied the [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), and experimented with various DOM traversing operators, but must be overlooking something simple. What operator should replace `xxxx` in my example above? From the API description, I thought `closest` should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: add a `"` here : `$(".checkbox")`

Comment: Also, if your form is more complex than just these fields, considering using an `id` for each form element to identify them and then the selector in jQuery will be `#yourID`, e.g. `$('#thecheckbox').change( ... ) `

Comment: thanks @NiklasLindblad, unfortunately my form is dynamic, and this section of code is repeated a variable number of times. While I could code a unique identifier, I think in this case DOM traversal is a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this group of elements is always encapsulated within that `.container` div element then this should work:

```
$(this).closest('div.conainer').find('.select')
```

This is using `closest` to traverse up the DOM hierarchy (parent elements) and then `find` to traverse back down (child elements).

Comment: works perfectly, thanks! The extra step was what I needed (plus I had a syntax error).